# P3v2 underlying virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-app-service-plans

Please confirm that the underlying virtual machine for the Azure App Service Premium P3v2 tier is the D3 v2, as shown below:

[image: Dv2 Series]